# Multi subplots how to adjust

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Here is the code for creating subplots and the graphs look like what's shown in the attached image. Is there a way to adjust the graphs so they look good and identical in size?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(path)
merged = df[df["test"].isin(['viral_load'])]
g = merged.groupby('id')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(g.ngroups, sharex=True, figsize=(8, 6))

for i, (id, d) in enumerate(g):
    ax = d.plot.line(x='months', y='result', ax=axes[i], title=id)
    ax.legend().remove()

fig.tight_layout()
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvFhv.png) you can see the result of the above code.

Comment: change `figsize=(8, 6)` to have a larger height, e.g. `figsize=(8, 12)`

Comment: You can also try 2 or more columns of subplots. Instead of a title, `ax.set_ylabel(id, rotation=0)`?  Maybe also `sharey=True` to make the curves easier to compare? Hide the top and right spines (`ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)`) to have less clutter.

Comment: See also [matplotlib's ridge plot tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/create-ridgeplots-in-matplotlib/) and seaborn's [ridge plot example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html)

Comment: All super helpful comments. Was able to make it work! Thanks.